# need to run javascripts on iframe which loads an external domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

`mysite.com` has an iframe which loads some `differentsite.com.`

need to run javascript on this loaded iframe document.

`Single Origin Policy` kicks in.

i resort to using proxy. its slow, creates bottleneck, unable to fully render the site (JS is not rendered).

Alternatives ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try `window.postMessage(message, origin)` (it would be `parent.postMessage` from the iframe and `iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage` from the top page) for all of the latest major browsers (Firefox, IE, Safari, Chrome, etc.) and changing/polling `window.name` for old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The first question would be, do you have control over the secondary domains, or are you able to persuade the webmasters of these to add additional components?

If so you could easily use [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) to call methods across the domain boundry.
Demos of this can be viewed [here](http://easyxdm.net/wiki/Demos.ashx)