# Searching Across Domain iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [need to run javascripts on iframe which loads an external domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619191/need-to-run-javascripts-on-iframe-which-loads-an-external-domain)

This seems like it just shouldn't be a difficult problem, but apparently it is.

I just have a simple page that uses an iFrame to incorporate another website that is located on a different server (cnn.com, for instance).

Now on the parent page, I just want to be able to search the iFrame for a certain word and have it tell me if that word is present on the iFrame page.  So for example, if cnn.com is my iframe page, I may want the parent page to tell me whether or not the word "Irene" appears on the iframe page.  So far I just cannot get this to work.

Is this possible?  Is it prohibited by the same origin policy?
Any work-around suggestions?

I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The parent page cannot access the contents of the IFRAME, or any frame if that matters. Otherwise you could open any page, like your Facebook profile, in a frame and read it contents on a hostile site.

You need to control the remote site and inject search logic there if you want to manipulate what happens inside IFRAME.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do with JavaScript because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

The only way you can access the content is if you use a proxy on your server to grab the page and redisplay it on your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible due to many security reasons.

This article might give you more insight

http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 0):

Do to security concerns you can't acess anothers iframes content inside the browser.

If you have your mind absolutely set on doing this, you could use the [cross domain jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/).

You then can do the following using yahoo's server as a proxy.

```
$('#container').load('http://google.com'); // SERIOUSLY!

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://news.bbc.co.uk',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var headline = $(res.responseText).find('a.tsh').text();
        alert(headline);
    }
});
```

James Padolsey blogged about it [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/).